# J2me Update Container List with changed ListModel

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form

I'm using lwuit Container list with Cell Renderer to display an image grid. For network availability purposes, I want to display a default image and change it to the fetched image after download completes. I'm also having problems detecting the completed download. I'm using a thread queue to minimize amount of threads running. How can i notify a method that updates the model when download is complete? How best can I update the list with the new model? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can change the list model on the fly. That way you can fetch the images with a thread queue and the update the model when the image fetching is complete